Circular definition of female and ovum?
The Britannica defines the egg (ovum) as "the female sex cell, or gamete." It then defines "female" as "If only eggs are produced, the reproductive gland is an ovary, and the primary sex is female". The two definitions are circular.
If a new species which can produce two kinds of sex cells is found, what is the exact rule to determine which is an ovum or sperm? By size (the bigger is the ovum), by shape (the round one is the ovum), by movement (which travels in the medium is the sperm, but what if both can travel), or else?
Species have various ways of reproduction. For example, both sexes of marine mussels release sex cells into sea to fertilize, so the conventional intuition of sex (who bears the offspring is female) is not enough.

Just found it's already answered here.

In that case you should delete the question or request closure.
